# Downloading black TIFF files

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have been downloading Sentinel2 and Sentinel3 images for Convolutional nerual networks but I keep getting black TIFF files.

Can you check my code?
I have been using the GEETOOLS by fitoprincipe, can be viewed here: [link](https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor).

The code:

```
var start = ee.Date("2018-04-01")
var end = ee.Date("2018-12-30")

var region = ee.FeatureCollection(allRegions.filterMetadata("system:index","equals","00000000000000000000"));

var filter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.date(start, end),
  ee.Filter.bounds(region))

var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

var s2_dates = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterDate(start,end)
  .filterBounds(region)

var dates = s2_dates
    .map(function(image) {
      return ee.Feature(null, {'date': image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')})
    })
    .distinct('date')
    .aggregate_array('date')


var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterDate(start,end)
  .filterBounds(region)
  .map(function (image) {
    return image
      .normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
      .updateMask(image.select('QA60').not())
      .rename('S2')
      .clip(region)
      .set('date', image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'))

  })

var s3 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S3/OLCI') 
  .filterDate(start,end)
  .filterBounds(region)
  .map(function (image) {
    return image
      .select(['Oa17_radiance', 'Oa08_radiance'])
      .divide(ee.Image([0.00493004, 0.00876539]))
      .normalizedDifference(['Oa17_radiance', 'Oa08_radiance'])
      .rename('S3')
      .clip(region)
      .set('date', image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'))
  })

var s3_dis = s3.distinct('date')


print("S2",s2)
print("S3",s3_dis)


batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(s2, 's2_images', {name: '{system_date}'})
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(s3_dis, 's3_images', {name: '{system_date}'})
```

The reason I am using this tool is to prevent manually downloading every single image.

Comment: What are you viewing them with when you've downloaded them? They can look black in an image viewer because data in TIFFs needs to be interpreted as RGB and scaled to be acceptible as a visual image. It might not even have three bands. Load into a GIS and inspect *the raw data*. What do you get?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, didn't know that. Is there a way to transform them into a grayscaled jpg or png? This is what I will be feeding my network with.

Comment: Hi Sahar, I know this is a weird comment to make but I just saw this question as I am reading in bed. If no one else has helped you by the time I wake up, I will reply with some help. I know date data can be challenging.

Comment: Hey @David, any chance you can help me with that? :) Hope you had a good sleep ;)

Comment: @SaharAttia, please send me one of the problem TIFs to david.holcomb@gmail and I will have a look! We can talk on email to not flood this here.

Comment: @David can you please check your mail?

Comment: @SaharAttia, I saw your email late but I replied 20 hours ago. It shows sent, you may want to check again for my reply.